# Best practice for offline website in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm building an app that requires downloading a lot of html5 content.  Essentially it works similar to the magazine apps you see for iPad, except instead of using images, it will use UIWebViews and HTML.

My question is what would be the best method for storing this.  I was thinking either a downloaded zip file that gets unzipped into the bundle and contains the html files, images, css, etc. or putting all the html in the database and just having the images, css, videos, etc. downloaded and put in the bundle.

Some considerations:

Many links will be local to the device, but some will be to outside sites.

I will need to be able to do full text search on all html content.

The size of the content will vary.

On a side note, I would love to be pointed in the right direction as far as setting up paging with UIWebViews.  Potentially a lot of UIWebViews.

Thanks,
Brandon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could download first an file that reflects the structure of the website images, css, htmls.

Then you parse this file and start download each file and save them to documents directory (you don't save in database because you could have big images and that will be slow you could save the paths of them). Afther thad just do an request to the local html.

Edit: 
You can catch the request in the webView delegate  and see if it is internal or external

> webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
>   Sent before a web view begins loading
>   content.
>
> - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest
>     *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType

[UIWebViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView%3ashouldStartLoadWithRequest%3anavigationType%3a)

Comment: I was thinking the css, js, images, etc. would be actual files in the bundle.  Then the HTML would be in the db to make full text search work nice.  Does that sound like a good possibility?  And how would I tell the difference between and outside link and a local link?  I can create my own url schema for the app, but that seems to be for opening the app from safari rather than processing it in app.

Comment: If it is an outside link you can load it in to your web view without open the safari app. And you can search in your html without saving it in db, you can load the html in some strings and use nspredicate to filter them.

Comment: But when the HTML is loaded in the web view, will it be able to tell whether it's an outside link or an internal link?  Or will I have to add a url schema and catch those calls?

Comment: Core Data puts images outside the database if necessary.

Answer (score 5):

This question can be pretty easily answered by looking at the first and best HTML5 overview book out right now... And the best part it is published under the CC license.

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/offline.html <- is a whole chapter on cacheing webapps and is a great jumping off point for your application.

It's not difficult, and it's cutting edge, what's cooler than that.

If you are really serious about getting this application to work offline well then it really shouldn't be summarized beyond the link.

Although I do have more resources that were at the bottom of that chapter

### Standards:

- [Offline web applications](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html) in the HTML5 specification

### Browser vendor documentation:

- [Offline resources in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Offline_resources_in_Firefox)
- [HTML5 offline application cache](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/OfflineApplicationCache/OfflineApplicationCache.html),
  part of the [Safari client-side
  storage and offline](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) applications
  programming guide

### Tutorials and demos:

- [Gmail for mobile HTML5 series: using
  appcache to launch offline - part
  1](https://googlecode.blogspot.com/2009/04/gmail-for-mobile-html5-series-using.html)
- Gmail for mobile HTML5 series: using
  appcache to launch offline - part
  2
- [Gmail for mobile HTML5 series: using
  appcache to launch offline - part
  3](https://googlecode.blogspot.com/2009/05/gmail-for-mobile-html5-series-part-3.html)
- [Debugging HTML5 offline application
  cache](http://jonathanstark.com/blog/2009/09/27/debugging-html-5-offline-application-cache/)
- [an HTML5 offline image editor and
  uploader application](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/02/an-html5-offline-image-editor-and-uploader-application/)
- [20 Things I Learned About Browsers
  and the Web](http://www.20thingsilearned.com/), an advanced demo
  that uses the application cache and
  other HTML5 techniques

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a look.  But there are a lot of iOS specific components too, not sure I can do the whole thing as an HTML 5 app.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself, but you may want to take a look at [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)'s [ASIWebPageRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIWebPageRequest) class.

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest is dead and bad because based on CFHTTPStream.

Comment: I haven't done much in iOS lately but on my last projects I was using AFNetworking. Can you elaborate on why ASIHTTPRequest is bad? (apart from being discontinued; note that my previous post is over 2 years old)

Comment: I have two sources. One is a well known Apple engineer: https://devforums.apple.com/message/702169#702169

And the other is the author of ASIHTTP himself: http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D;

Comment: I was expecting to find a bit more of information as to Why relying on CFHTTPStream is a "bad thing", but in both links the only reason appeared to be the fact that it's a "legacy API" (instead of their more recent higher-level APIs). Still, thanks for the first link.