# UIWebView render data offline

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I using a UIWebView in my application and I want to allow the user to view the contents of this UIWebView object without being connected to the internet.

I thought of the following approach:

1. Fetch a .zip file from the server which consists of all the data(.html, .css, .js and image files)
2. Unzip this file to a particular location on the device (Suppose A).
3. Make the UIWebView object render the files from the location A.
4. We will only be downloading the .zip file for the very first time when the user launches the application.

Will this be the correct approach?

Is there a better approach which can be followed to make the UIWebview render html data offline?

Comment: Take a look on this may helps you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732508/best-practice-for-offline-website-in-ios

Answer (score 1):

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

Use above code to display the webpage when you offline.